# Network security

Tags: java-me, cryptography, elliptic-curve

How could I generate curve points for elliptic curve cryptography in Java?

Answer (score 2):

You would be advised to consider using the [bouncycastle java libary](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html), which has support for elliptic curves and the Java ME. Look for the lcrypto-j2me links on their [latest releases](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia: [Elliptic curve cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography)

> For current cryptographic purposes, an elliptic curve is a plane curve which consists of the points satisfying the equation

```
 y^2 = x^3 + ax + b
```

> along with a distinguished point at infinity, denoted \infty. (The coordinates here are to be chosen from a fixed finite field of characteristic not equal to 2 or 3, or the curve equation will be somewhat more complicated.) This set together with the group operation of the elliptic group theory form an Abelian group, with the point at infinity as identity element. The structure of the group is inherited from the divisor group of the underlying algebraic variety.

Further on, we read:

> Several discrete logarithm-based protocols have been adapted to elliptic curves, replacing the group `(Zp)^x` times with an elliptic curve:
>
> - the [elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) key agreement scheme is based on the Diffie–Hellman scheme,
> - the [Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA) is based on the Digital Signature Algorithm,
> - the [ECMQV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMQV) key agreement scheme is based on the MQV key agreement scheme.

This should be enough information to get you started.